# Need to strip messy data sets with quotations using Python

Tags: python, file, csv, parsing

I'm still fairly new to parsing in Python so I needed a bit of help on some things regarding concatenation. I have one .asc file and on .dat file that both have structures like this:

```
sta cnt assgnum cty pdpass  ptype   patnum
"IL"    ""  1   "Chicago"   10030271    "0" 3930271
"PA"    ""  1   "Bedford"   10156902    "0" 3930272
"MO"    ""  1   "St. Louis" 10112031    "0" 3930273
"IL"    ""  1   "Chicago"   10030276    "0" 3930276
```

and the .dat like this:

```
cod cod_fix pdpass  standard_name   uspto_assignee
"US institute"  32  12832332    "& AEROSPACE FOUND" 835951
"02 US corporation" "No change" 11624193    "& COMMUNICATIONS"  721167
"03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned"    "No change" 12549858    "& DESIGN LTD"  806186
"03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned"    "No change" 11170486    "& FR"  182855
```

It's pretty ugly. So I'm trying to save both as **.csv files** individually and strip them both of all the quotation marks (in sta, cty, ptype, cod, etc...)

The end goal is to merge the two data sets together under the same *unique identifier* (**pdpass**) but first they need to be stripped.

My code for stripping is like:

```
import csv
import re

with open("C:\\......FILE.asc", "r") as fin:
    with open("C:\.....FILE.csv", "w") as fout:

        for line in fin:
            newline = map(str.strip, line.split('"'))
            csv.writer(fout).writerow(newline)
```

This gives me some wonky results in the formatting. Not too sure where to head. Anyone?

Comment: your data cannot be a CSV(comma separated values), if you strip the quotes! As `"03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned"`  would be two separate fields `03 Foreign corp` and `incl. state-owned` after you remove the quotes as they are separated by comma.

Comment: I see. Could we just keep them in their own respective formats, read them, then merge the two on the identifiers?

Comment: @shreyasg already has the answer for you!

Answer (score 1):

These files look tab-separated. If so, just use the pandas library to read it as a csv, with tab as a delimiter.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("C:\\......FILE.asc", sep = '\t')
```

You can then clean up the quotes by using a map or apply on each row.

Comment: I have used pandas to do this using the reader and then concatenating it with `d_f = pd.concat[(file1, file2)]` but then I think an issue comes in with `d_f.to_csv(......)` 

When they compile all of the data in each column it just stacks into one large column rather than separate rows under each header. Any way to make this work?

Comment: Why have the OP install pandas just to do something that the built-in `csv` module can do?

Answer (score 0):

It's late (in my timezone). This code indicates a basic way of reading the two files, and of merging them on the `pdpass` variable, assuming that the input files are tab-delimited. (If they're not tab-delimited I can offer other code.)

Almost forgot!: I changed some of the `pdpass` values in one of the files so that records in it would 'connect' to some corresponding records in the other file.

```
import csv

complete = {}
with open('FILE.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        complete[row['pdpass']] = [row[_] for _ in ['sta', 'cnt', 'assgnum', 'cty', 'ptype', 'patnum']]

with open('FILE.dat') as datfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(datfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        complete[row['pdpass']].extend(row[_] for _ in ['cod', 'cod_fix', 'standard_name', 'uspto_assignee'])

for pdpass in complete:
    print (pdpass, complete[pdpass])
```

Here's the resulting output:

```
10030276 ['IL', '', '1', 'Chicago', '0', '3930276', '02 US corporation', 'No change', '& COMMUNICATIONS', '721167']
10156902 ['PA', '', '1', 'Bedford', '0', '3930272', '03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned', 'No change', '& FR', '182855']
10030271 ['IL', '', '1', 'Chicago', '0', '3930271', '03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned', 'No change', '& DESIGN LTD', '806186']
10112031 ['MO', '', '1', 'St. Louis', '0', '3930273', 'US institute', '32', '& AEROSPACE FOUND', '835951']
```

Input files:

FILE.csv

```
sta cnt assgnum cty pdpass  ptype   patnum
"IL"    ""  1   "Chicago"   10030271    "0" 3930271
"PA"    ""  1   "Bedford"   10156902    "0" 3930272
"MO"    ""  1   "St. Louis" 10112031    "0" 3930273
"IL"    ""  1   "Chicago"   10030276    "0" 3930276
```

FILE.dat

```
cod cod_fix pdpass  standard_name   uspto_assignee
"US institute"  32  10112031    "& AEROSPACE FOUND" 835951
"02 US corporation" "No change" 10030276    "& COMMUNICATIONS"  721167
"03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned"    "No change" 10030271    "& DESIGN LTD"  806186
"03 Foreign corp, incl. state-owned"    "No change" 10156902    "& FR"  182855
```